# Rating bar value

Tags: java, android

I am a complete newbie in android. I have developed an app with help of google which has 3 activities:

1. quiz activity
2. result activity
3. high score activity

My result activity has a rating bar to show the score in stars (1 star for score of 1), but I don't know how to save the number of stars scored in the quiz activity to the high score activity.